# how do i plumb this rough-in?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement

The future bathroom in my basement has been roughed-in by the builder. Spot where the tub / shower goes was covered over by a square plastic tub (a "dap-out", if the spelling I see online is correct).

I removed the plastic, and under the gravel out there, all I find is a diagonal pipe that runs horizontally. There's no vertical riser, though it does look like there's probably a slight down-grade towards the sewer cleanout.

There's no P-trap; I'm assuming I'll have to build one as part of the fixture here.

How do I install a tub/shower over this riser-less rough-in? Should I install a riser and connect to this horizontal pipe, hoping that waste will flow through normally without settling down at the spot?

Or, should I call a qualified plumber and have them worry about it?

I don't have pictures at the moment, but will be able to upload a few later tonight.

Edit: Here's a photo of the setup. Top right of the photo is a vent stack, to the right is the 4" toilet rough in, and one sewer cleanout is towards top left, around 15feet away: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=984BD8DB48E0EE68!84829&authkey=!AJ6s_mgiiNRkLm8&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: Some pictures would be helpful.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson, yep. I'll do that when I get back home tonight.